# Display PDF files REST API

Tags: python, rest, flask-restful

I am using RESTful API with python and flask to list all PDF files of a folder. The PDF filenames are displayed with their complete path. For example, `http://127.0.0.1:5000/getPDFs` shows the following

```
test1.pdf /home/PATH/test1.pdf
test2.pdf /home/PATH/test2.pdf
```

Now, I would like to add a link to all the paths and when the path is clicked, the PDF files should be displayed on the browser. If I click the `/home/PATH/test1.pdf` it should go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/getPDFs/test1.pdf` and display the pdf file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a route that points to the pdf you are looking for, in your case:

```
@app.route('/getPDFs/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['PATH'],
                               filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Your file should be visible by your flask app. You can find the documentation for `send_from_directory` here:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: Thanks !! It seems that I was looking for this solution.